# why isn't z-index working in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I've created a top level menu with dropdowns but the drop down isn't coming to the front in IE.  Chrome, FF, and Safari work great.

My code looks like this:

```
<li id="search"><a href="#search" class="drop" >Search</a>
    <div class="drop2columns dropcontent">
        <div class="col_2">
            <ul>
                <li id="search_basic"><a href="#test1">Test1</a></li>
                <li id="search_advanced"><a href="#test2">Test2</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The css files look like this:

```
#menu .drop2columns {width: 130px;}

#menu .col_2 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#menu .col_2 {width:130px;}
```

What am I missing?  Like I said this only happens with IE (versions 7,8, and 9)

Comment: On my website, I actually stopped supporting IE. If anyone tries to view my website using IE, it redirects them to a page that tells them to get chrome or firefox. (it would be better for everyone if people didn't use internet explorer)  Then again, I'm making this website for pleasure, not for business. If it was for business I would, inevitably, have to support IE.

Comment: I wish I could do the same...IE is one of the worst browsers but unfortunately a lot of people still use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index and IE was always a nightmare.

There's several workarounds about, see 
http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/ 
for one of them.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` doesn’t work correctly in Internet Explorer: positioned elements create a new stacking context, starting with a `z-index` of `0`. To get around this you can make the parent element positioned (e.g., `position: relative`), and set its `z-index` to a value higher than that of the child.